# Issues with common configuration file per solution with multiple azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

We have a common configuration file for the solution with multiple azure function, some config settings are specific to particualar azure function.
When solution is deployed to function apps in azure, in App Settings, we are having to set all configuration properties for all functions even if that function is not using that specific config settings.

Comment: What part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings) is not clear?

Comment: how do you deploy your azure resources ? you can use an ARM template to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

AppSettings are all shared across functions in a Function App. As Jeroen mentioned in the comments this is by design.

You mention that each function has very different configuration. One thing to consider is if you are finding that each of your functions do very different things and possibly also scale differently (e.g. one handles thousands of messages while the other handles a few http requests a month) it may be appropriate to break those into separate function apps and in that case they would get their own settings but I would not recommend this solely to get more granular app settings or you'll end up with a maintenance nightmare of lots of function apps.

If you're having some problems managing numerous appsettings I would automate it through a CI\CD pipeline or as Thomas mentioned in the comments see if you can automate it through ARM templates when the function app is deployed.